# How do I determine the type a generic container is storing?

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm interrogating an object properties looking for ones that are of a specific type `TypeOfInterest` or are generics storing object of `TypeOfInterest` .  How can I tell for a `List(of T)` that `T` is `TypeOfInterest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page shows how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.96).aspx

In short, you get the Type value from your List and then use the GetGenericArguments method.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<string>).GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YourList is List<TypeOfInterest>
```

If you want to make sure that the list contains only variables of that class, then you'll need to check each one of them.